# Proof that any finite subgroup of $SO(2)$ must be cyclic

Tags: group-theory

How do I prove that any finite subgroup of $SO(2)$ must be cyclic?

Also, what are all the finite subgroups of $O(2)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not quite sure what you mean by "prove" in this case, but $SO(2)$ is the group of rotations in the plane. A finite subgroup must be the group of rotations by an integral fraction of $2\pi$, and will always be a cyclic group because you can see rotations as cycles.

Take, for example, any regular $n$-gon centered at the origin in the plane and number its vertices consecutively from $1$ to $n$. Then a rotation by $2\pi/n$ will take $1$ into $2$, $2$ into $3$, etc, in a cyclic fashion.

The group $O(2)$ includes rotations and reflections. Its finite subgroups will be dihedral groups.

Comment: Thank you very much ! it puts things in context for me.